# Yii disable link after update

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I am looking for a correct syntax to disable a CHtml link when the value is "1"
in clistview.

This is my code. I tried some arrays, but always got error. I do not know the correct syntax to make it work.

```
<?php echo CHtml::link($data->EstadoDetalle==1?'Entregada':'No entregada', array('estado', 'id'=>$data->CodigoDetalleReceta)); ?>
```

Comment: what was error message?

Comment: With this code i dont get error,i just do not know the correct syntax to disable Entregada when EstadoDetalle is "1",i am new to php and yii and i just do not know how to write the correct array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it should be

```
<?php echo CHtml::link($data->EstadoDetalle == 1 ? 'No entregada' : 'Entregada', array('estado', 'id'=>$data->CodigoDetalleReceta)); ?>
```

It means when `$data->EstadoDetalle` is `1` then `No entregada` will be shown else `Entregada`.
It is exactly

```
if($data->EstadoDetalle == 1){
    //No entregada
}else{
    //Entregada
}
```

If you totally hide the link then you can like below

```
if($data->EstadoDetalle != 1){
    echo CHtml::link('Entregada', array('estado', 'id'=>$data->CodigoDetalleReceta));
}
```

Also provide you another way

```
echo CHtml::link(
    'Link Title',
    ($data->CodigoDetalleReceta == 1) ? array('estado', 'id'=>$data->CodigoDetalleReceta) : 'javascript:void(0);'
);
```